# Google reCAPTCHA g-recpatcha-response has no value in PHP

Tags: php, html, captcha, recaptcha, contact-form

**p.s: I gave up on this as I found no solution and implemented my own php captcha that worked a treat :) - http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/captcha/**

I have spent many hours & days trying to solve this problem but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have read a lot of different tutorials & questions online.

Just to keep in mind, my PHP level is fairly basic.

I cannot seem to get the 'g-recaptcha-response' $_POST value in my php file.

I have summarised the important code needed below...

## File 1: contact.php

Before Head Tags

```
<?php 
session_start(); // start php session

// Setup session variables to save the form data
if( isset($_SESSION['contact_form_values']) ){
    extract( $_SESSION['contact_form_values'] );
}

include('contactengine.php');
?>
```

In Head Tags

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script><!-- reCAPTCHA form -->
```

Between the Form tags
Action="" so that it posts to itself which has the contactengine.php file included so that it runs through only when the user clicks the submit button?

```
<form class="contactform" method="POST" action="">

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc92gkTAAAAAFKjZEOlY0cg9G8ubmlVoC13Xf3T"></div>
```

## File 2: contactengine.php

Between this

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

I have

```
if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ){
        $captchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
```

Now this is the point where the variable $captchaResponse isn't being populated as I output the value of it like this:

```
if( !$captchaResponse ){ // check the POST recaptcha response value
        $resultMsg = 'Please check the captcha form. - '.$captchaResponse;
    }
```

Therefore I get no visible output of the response code in the $resultMsg string.

The only thing I could think is effecting it, is including the contactengine.php file at the beginning in contact.php. And having the action as ="". But this is what the tutorial guided me to do. So maybe not...

I used http://www.9lessons.info/2014/12/google-new-recaptcha-using-php-are-you.html as the guide.

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: possible useful link: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to watch your network traffic, see what happens behind the scenes. Also don't output unfiltered POST values (to avoid XSS attacks)

Comment: Thanks @m02ph3u5, I just set it up like that for debugging purposes. Also I have used the dev tools in chrome and the response is being returned in json but is called 'uvresp'. I even tried this name in replace of 'g-recaptcha-response' and no luck. Ill keep looking

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` tell you?

Comment: Wait a sec, does google fire a post request back? If yes you shouldn't be able to see this in your dev tools. If you have to parse the response of your own request you won't have the results in $_POST.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 so what would be the best solution? Do I have to process the response value using javscript?

Comment: And regardless of dev tools, it's not even been populated when I check if the isset of it either.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there! You just need to query Google's API.

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}

if (!$captcha) {
    // Captcha wasn't checked, do something...
    exit;
}

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEYGOESHERE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($response.success == false) {
    // Captcha failed! Do something!
} else {
    // Captcha is valid! Do something else!
}
```

Replace `SECRETKEYGOESHERE` with your actual secret key, and you're set!

Comment: Hi, Sorry I didn't make it clear but I already have this part set up. The 'g-recaptcha-response' $_POST value is false on isset statement for me

Comment: btw, he will need fopen wrappers enabled for this approach - many hosted solutions have em disabled

Comment: The `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` will be empty if the checkbox isn't checked. If it is checked, you will get a long string as a result, which will be queried at `$response` in my code above. Is it sill empty when you complete the captcha?

Comment: I've experienced before that the `include` isn't loaded 100% before PHP continues to run the script - what happens if you put it into the same file, and not via an include?? I can't really spot any errors in your code.

Comment: No luck on this one, I'm thinking of leaving it and finding a different reCAPTCHA script...

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Thank you so much! I've had quite a lot of difficulties implementing reCAPTCHA in my particular case. Had some difficulties setting up a proxy to get around the cross site request when validating the response token, integrating it into my form validation, etc. When I finally got it running locally and uploaded it to my hosting environment I was stumped at this empty response. The fopen wrappers were the issue in my case. I was also just about to give up on it entirely, glad I was able to get it to work in the end thanks to your comment!